Problem Installing Specific Python Package - Error Details
Hi, i try to download package python. I already delete this package but still the same error too:

This is my command for install, since i cant use virtual enviroment's pip. i use the global pip

"C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" -m pip install -r "C:\Users\wmafhanapi\OneDrive - ONG&ONG Pte Ltd\Documents\Project Development\dev_project\development_iWeb2\requirements.txt"

The Main Error

    The user requested six==1.12.0
    behave 1.2.6 depends on six>=1.11
    google-auth 2.6.2 depends on six>=1.9.0
    google-auth-httplib2 0.1.0 depends on six
    grpcio 1.45.0 depends on six>=1.5.2
    html5lib 1.1 depends on six>=1.9
    imapclient 2.1.0 depends on six
    parse-type 0.6.2 depends on six>=1.15

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts```


You have specific version requirements that exclude each other. More specifically it looks like your requirements.txt defines six==1.12.0 while parse-type 0.6.2 requires a higher version of six (at least 1.15). You have to update the file.

Note that if you don't use the virtualenv's pip your virtualenv won't be able to use these packages even if you can install them.
